# Ambiguous imports in Scala

Tags: scala, import

I'm writing a small simulation program in Scala. It is actor-based so I've created a file `messages.scala` that contains all of the messages that are valid in the system.

Outside of this, I have a management component, `management.scala` and a file that defines the nodes and links classes `nodes.scala`. Management and node files both `import sim.messages._` and then management does `import sim.nodes._` as it needs to be able to instantiate things from that file.

The problem comes with one message type `Tick` that is used by both `management.scala` and `nodes.scala`. Upon compiling the management component, I get:

```
error: reference to Tick is ambiguous;
it is imported twice in the same scope by
import sim.nodes._
and import sim.messages._
```

I tried removing the import of messages in the management component since they were apparently already imported in to this scope but then they couldn't find them anymore. Ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
import sim.nodes._
import sim.nodes.{ Tick => NodesTick }
```

and/or

```
import sim.messages._
import sim.messages.{ Tick => MessagesTick }
```

Of course, you will have to rename the references to `Tick` with the right one.

Comment: The logic behind this being just to get one of the references out of the way by renaming it? I used the nodes version of your code so that I could continue to just use "Tick" from messages and I still get the same error. Potentially because I am still doing underscore to import all?

Comment: taking inspiration from your idea, I came up with "import sim.messages._" and "import sim.nodes.{Tick=>_,_}" Seems to do the trick by assigning Tick to nothing and then importing the rest. This seems to be the appropriate way to do this because according to something I just read, once something is imported it cant be undone. Therefore, doing it in two steps imports the Tick definition I dont want and then I'm importing it again under a different alias. Anyway, sorted now, thanks for the help.